# how to select from 2 tables with 2 or more conditions with same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

table1 = id --- speciality ---- city,...

table2 = id --- latm1 ---- longm1 ---- latm2----longm2 ,...(2 more lat and long)

table3  =id --- latd1 ---- longd1 ---- latd2----longd2 ,...(2 more lat and long)

id's are the same , and all lats and longs are for one person with that id(he works for 4 hospital and 4 other institude)

consider this varbiales that comes by $_POST:

$speciality;

$userlat;

$userlong;

I want to say this :
     select everything from table1 where his speciality="$speciality" and he is near this    lat="$userlat",long="$userlong" with distance 4km;

I know it sounds ridiculous but that is what it is :(

I'm using this mehtod for geting nearest latlang in my database:

```
 $sql = "SELECT 
  *,
  (
    6371 * ACOS(
      COS(RADIANS($userlat)) * COS(RADIANS(latm1)) * COS(RADIANS(langm1) - RADIANS($userlang)) + SIN(RADIANS($userlat)) * SIN(RADIANS(latm1))
    )
  ) AS distance 
FROM
  ? 
HAVING distance < 20 ";
```

but as you see , it only searches for latm1 and longm1 , not the other ones from other tables(for example : latm2 and longm2 from table2 or latd3 and longd3 from table3)

thank for your patience;

Comment: How these 3 tables relates to each other any relation between them ?

Comment: YES like I said , every table has the same id for each person

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do... what is the differences between `table2` and `table3`?

Comment: what do you mean by "difference"?
there are 3 tables , each table has an id,and some other colomuns
for a person , I make a row in each table with same id 
OK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

in simplified syntax:

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.id, table1.val, table2.id, table2.val 
FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id";
```

I leave it at times in this simple example.